# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'o' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a laravel / vuejs 2 application and I've recently encountered the following in my console which I can't figure out how to solve.

[image: Console screen grab]
I've no idea what's caused this to occur and it doesn't seem to stop my application from working however it annoys me that it's in the console.

Comment: This happens when `o` is declared as a `const`

Comment: you need to provide more info than that, also maybe refresh your app if you are not declaring `o` after using `let`, `const` to declare it

Comment: Where would I be declaring this though as I haven't used in my application o as a const.

Comment: Turns out it's an extension I have installed :/

Comment: Same problem: **angular 2.3.1 + typescript 2.0.10 + node 8.9.3 + webpack 2.2.0**. For start app: **ng serve**.

Comment: @Dev.Wol What extension?

Comment: @Colin Ghostery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** Ghostery got back to me quickly and have fixed this and released the updated version.

This is caused by the recent version of [Ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com/).  I have submitted a bug report to company and will update this answer once the bug has been fixed and the fix is released.

In the meantime, the only workaround I have found is disabling the extension while using dev tools.  To make this more manageable, you may want to install Chrome Canary for dev work, since it can be installed in parallel with Chrome Stable.

Comment: I can confirm this. Disabling Ghostery fixed the issue for me too.